# one express server and two or multiple angular clients

Tags: angularjs, express

fullstack to build my app
What I'm trying to do is having multiple angular clients with one server.
To be specific, I want a website and a mobile website.
the function of both sites is same. Thus, I want only one express server using REST API.

Since I'm using angular-fullstack, I already made a website(angular app) and REST API(express) server.
I want to add another angular app to my angular-fullstack project.

Is there any documents about those kind of structure? or any advice?
thanks!